# vncviewer is losing caps lock, which I want to remap anyways

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

I am on a linux system and using vncviewer to connect to other linux servers.

On my home system, I use setxkbmap to remap caps to control, like any decent human being:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier
```

When I run vncviewer, I find that my caps key does nothing in my VNC windows, so I can't remap it.

If I run xev in the VNC remote system, then there are no keycaps or activity from pressing the capslock.  It's just thrown away.

I have the 'GrabKeyboard' option set to 1, so it should be sending all my keyboard events to the remote server, but it's not happening.

How can I figure out either how to send the control mapping of my keyboard to the remote server, or at least send the caps lock event so I can remap it on the remote server?

Comment: Oddly difficult to find any solution to this issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope - I'm guessing that vnc is grabbing the raw key events and somehow the remapped ones are lost?  Who knows.